# "are of particular interest" or "are of a particular interest"

Tags: indefinite-article, determiners, countability

> Verbal expressions are **of particular interest**.

Is the above sentence correct or we should add an *a* before *particular*?

> Verbal expressions are **of a particular interest**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression is "of particular interest" (in the negative, "of no particular interest").

"interest" in "of ... interest" is non-count (see below) and, therefore, does not take the indefinite article. It can only take determiners like *some, certain, little*: *of **some/certain/little** interest*.

[image: Source]